# работа со строками, с++

Tags: c++, строки

каким алгоритмом с++ сравнивает две строки? есть ли смысл писать свой собственный (более оптимальный)?

Comment: есть два способа сравнивать строки - один в один и с помощью применения локалей. Первый способ, когда сравнивается два учатка памяти Вы вряд ли сможете написать быстрее.

Но в любом случае, если у Вас есть сомнения, пишите свой алгоритм и обкатывайте на бенчмарках.

Answer (score 7):

Библиотеки вылизываются годами. Вы уверены, что сможете улучшить то, над чем многие работали очень долго?

Но вот если у вас есть дополнительная информация, частный, а не общий случай - тогда конечно. Например, вы сравниваете строки, которые, как заведомо известно, в первых 10000 символов одинаковы. Или еще что-то, что может позволить не сравнивать подряд два участка памяти...

Answer (score 1):

Писать свой собственный компаратор для строк нет смысла. Есть готовые, например [`string::compare`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  std::string str1 ("Строка 1");
  std::string str2 ("Строка 2");

  if (str1.compare(str2) != 0)
    std::cout << str1 << " != " << str2 << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Результат:

> Строка 1 != Строка 2

Проверить и можно [тут](https://ideone.com/s7wX6L).

Можно использовать си-стиль, например [`strcmp`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strcmp/):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str1[] = "Строка 11";
  char str2[] = "Строка 22";

  if (strcmp(str1, str2) != 0)
    std::cout << str1 << " != " << str2 << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Результат:

> Строка 11 != Строка 22

[Проверка](https://ideone.com/Gxh90a)

Answer (score 1):

Зависит от того, где используется это сравнение.

Если будет производиться сравнение строк в большом документе(ах), то стоит обратить внимание на [Полнотекстовый поиск](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA).

Также следует рассмотреть алгоритмы [Поиска подстроки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8).